# Avoid Printing of code when running scripts in spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to DB from in spark shell using scripts in scala file.
when Connecting the script takes password from other location but it does print in console of spark shell.
I just want to avoid those.

Code in Scala is as below,

```
val config=Map("driver"->"drivername","url"->"dburl","user"->"username","password"->"741852963");
```

When loading this code in spark shell this prints the code in spark shell too. I want these alone part of to not print in spark console.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several ways to achieve this:

- You can wrap your config definition in an object. Spark shell will just output that an object is defined

```
scala> object ConfigHolder {
     | val config=Map("secret"->"value")
     | }
defined object ConfigHolder
```

You can then simply reference your config as `ConfigHolder.config` instead of `config`

- You can disable/re-enable output printing in the shell with the `:silent` command

```
scala> :silent

scala> val config=Map("secret"->"value")

scala> :silent
```

Of course, none of these actions prevent anyone with access to the spark shell from reading your credentials, it just prevents casual onlookers from seeing them.